# Laravel: ErrorException in helpers.php line 531:

Tags: php, forms, laravel

please help me to solve this strange problem. I have one page, which one of the parts is an HTML form with three fields and submit button. If i load the page, everything is fine. If i submit the form, it gives me that error:

```
ErrorException in helpers.php line 531:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: 
C:\xampp\htdocs\beta\resources\views\admin\table\partials\form.blade.php) 
(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\beta\resources\views\admin\table\partials\form.blade.php)
```

the form.blade.php includes the problematic form. Here is the code:

```
{!! Form::model($season, [
    'method' => 'post',
    'route' => ['admin.tables.show', $season->id]
]) !!}

@foreach($stages as $stage)
<div class="col-md-12 formleft">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('name') !!}
            {!! Form::text('name[]', $stage->name, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('url') !!}
            {!! Form::text('url[]', $stage->url, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('type_id', 'Type') !!}
            {!! Form::select('type_id[]', $types, $stage->type_id, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            {!! Form::hidden('id[]', $stage->id) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach

{!! Form::submit('Save stages', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}

<br>
```

The error is somewhere in the @foreach loop. I have removed the Form fields one by one, but every time it gives me the same error. Only if I remove all Form fields, than it works. If I leave the Form fields with no values, the errors come again. I have no idea what is going on.

To debug the code i have changed the @foreach loop like this:

```
@foreach($stages as $stage)
<div class="col-md-12 formleft">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('name') !!}
            {!! Form::text('name[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

But the error comes again. The problem is in the {!! Form() !!}, but why ?

Comment: Please show contents of `{{ dd($stage) }}` inside the loop.

Comment: you given one of the  Form::text fields an array.

Comment: show us the {{ dd($stage) }}

Comment: I dont think the problem is in $stage. If i replace $stage->name with some string and so for all fields, after submit it gives me the same error

Comment: @VinceCarter try to comment each field one by one and see when the error not shown.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is if the name doesn't allow for array notation. Which, I mean, it should, but everything else looks fine.

Comment: @SalarBahador i have tried that - it is in the description of the problem. It does not help. Only if i remove all fields there is no error.

Comment: @VinceCarter the code works perfectly with proper data, so if you'll want help, please post contents of the `{{ dd($stage) }}` or better `{{ ($stages) }}`

Comment: @JoelHinz if the form is not submitted it displays everything fine. The $stage state before and after the submitting is the same ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your naming method. you give all the input same name but no key. in this way, laravel thinks its an array. So put a counter before foreach and give every name a key, a number within the brackets. like this code below:

```
@php
    $i = 0;
@endphp
    @foreach($stages as $stage)
    <div class="col-md-12 formleft">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('name') !!}
                {!! Form::text('name[$i]', $stage->name, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('url') !!}
                {!! Form::text('url[$i]', $stage->url, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('type_id', 'Type') !!}
                {!! Form::select('type_id[$i]', $types, $stage->type_id, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                {!! Form::hidden('id[$i]', $stage->id) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   @php
    $i++
   @endphp
    @endforeach

    {!! Form::submit('Save stages', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}

    <br>
```

Or you can use $loop->index variable. The $loop->index is the index of the current loop iteration. so you can use `{!! Form::text('name[$loop->index]', $stage->name, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it works, but is still strange why only by submitting the form it does not work ?

Comment: You don't need to use `$i++`, you can use the `$loop` variable instead. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: @VinceCarter Any time! because every input must have a unique name. this way in the controller request knows how many inputs it has and each unique input has a value.

Comment: It's not because of that. It's because `model()` method repopulates submitted data. But still a good answer. @VinceCarter you should upvote the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin tnx for your support!

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin thank you too. I have up-voted the answer, haven't i ?

Comment: @VinceCarter no, you ticked it (chose as the best answer). But it's a good idea to say thank you by upvoting it too.